# how to run different files on xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I am brand new to Xcode.  I am working on different problems and I just  want to be able to run each file individually and switch between them.  I keep getting "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".  I think it has something to do with targeting? Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj4ho.png)

Comment: I would recommend you post the actual code, not an image of code.

Answer (score 0):

A program can have only one function `main`. If you want to manage different exercises, each in a separate file, do the following:

```
// main.cpp:
extern void exercise1();
extern void exercise2();   

int main() {
   exercise1();
   // exercise2();  // uncomment if you want exercise2 to be executed.
}

// exercise1.cpp:
void exercise1() {
   // your exercise1 "main" code goes here
}

// exercise2.cpp:
void exercise2() {
   // your exercise2 "main" code goes here
}
```

Comment: I see what you're doing.  I just want to build and run individual little programs separately, is this the easiest way to do so?  Thanks for the help man!

Comment: Little individual programs would mean several targets; you can add targets either through "File->New->Target" (e.g. a command line tool then); for each target, you can define the files to compile in the Build Phases tab. OK?